# will mysql write same value to the disk when value is the same in update?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

When I use update to modify the data in mysql:

```
update table set col1=A,col2=B,col3=C where col4=D;
```

If A and B are the same, and C is not, will mysql write these 3 cols to the disk?