# Combine multiple sql update statements into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following three update statements:

```
UPDATE mx m JOIN main_territorypricingavail a USING (tp_id) 
SET sd_price = a.price WHERE a.code = 'SDBUY';

UPDATE mx m JOIN main_territorypricingavail a USING (tp_id) 
SET hd_price = a.price WHERE a.code = 'HDBUY';

UPDATE mx m JOIN main_territorypricingavail a USING (tp_id) 
SET uhd_price = a.price WHERE a.code = 'UHDBUY';
```

Is it possible to combine these three into one statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `CASE` expressions here to do this in a single update:

```
UPDATE mx m
INNER JOIN main_territorypricingavail a
USING (tp_id)
SET
    sd_price  = CASE WHEN a.code = 'SDBUY'  THEN a.price ELSE sd_price END,
    hd_price  = CASE WHEN a.code = 'HDBUY'  THEN a.price ELSE hd_price END,
    uhd_price = CASE WHEN a.code = 'UHDBUY' THEN a.price ELSE uhd_price END;
```

From a performance point of view, MySQL will not overwrite a value to a column/record in an update if it notices that the value would not change.  So the penalty for the `ELSE` conditions happening often above may not be as bad as it looks ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364214/does-mysql-overwrite-a-column-of-same-value-on-update) for more information).

Comment: @Nick We posted at almost exactly the same time, you didn't need to delete.  Maybe just point out something I missed, and you're good to go.

Comment: Not a problem - highly unlikely I'll think of something you missed!